# Sunspot failing to index an integer belongs_to id field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sunspot, sunspot-rails

In the examples for sunspot [sunspot.github.com](http://sunspot.github.com), a `belongs_to :blog` association is indexed inside a `searchable` block with `integer :blog_id`. Later, the search can be constrained to a particular blog using `with(:blog_id, 1)`.

If have done this, except the association is for a `retailer` and the index is on `retailer_id`. Yet, when searching, there are no results returned as soon as I use `with(:retailer_id, 4)`. If this condition is left off, all of the results returned have a `retailer_id = 4`.

I have reindexed, numerous times. I've tried both sunspot_rails 1.3.3 and 2.0.0.

All of the other `text` fields appear to be indexing fine.

The query displayed in the Rails logs, going to solr, appears to include the proper fields.

What else might cause this?

Answer (score 0):

After attempting to `Sunspot.index(Item.first)` and seeing that the xml did include the retailer_id. I checked the logs for the import done by the rake task.

As it turns out, the problem that I was experiencing is because DataMapper does not create the association properties until after `DataMapper.finalize` is called. This never happens as a part of the included sunspot_rails tasks.rb for reindexing.

The quick solution for me was to simply copy over the rake task, and add the call to finalize after all the models are required.